# org-mode latex export: German ß character

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, utf-8

Is there a way to export to latex in a way that the German 'ß' ("scharfes S", "eszett") character stays? I'm using utf-8 input encoding, and Umlauts get exported well, but ß appears as capital SS in my documents, although it gets exported to html fine.

**Edit:** I just found out, when changing the inputencoding to utf8x, it works:

```
#+latex_header: \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
```

Comment: related: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/20062/exporting-unicode-characters-to-pdf-using-latex-from-org-mode/20812#20812