# Latex and Emacs

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

I have tried to export to Latex an Orgmode document that has some unicode characters not recognized (emojis). When compiling I get the error

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character  (U+1F525)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

I have nothing configured in my init file for Latex. I am just going with the prepackaged Prelude distribution.

I have read elsewhere that I should enable certain package or specify some headers? I am totlly null in Latex, but would like to render my ORG files in Latex.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exporting unicode characters to pdf using latex from org mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/20062/exporting-unicode-characters-to-pdf-using-latex-from-org-mode)

Comment: For emoji s you need a font that contains them.  There are some suggestions at https://stackoverflow.com/a/57076064/4050592 but this is a moving target.